# Use a 301 to Redirect any 404 from at the blog post level to the blog archive

Tags: redirect, htaccess, blog-page

In the .htaccess file, I am trying to write a 301 to catch any broken blog page links to redirect to the blog archive page?

so something like

```
Redirect 301 /blog-archive/category/{any 404} /blog-archive/
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/391256/edit) to provide some context. What does your `.htaccess` file look like?

Comment: You can't do this in `.htaccess` with WordPress (or any similar CMS), because only WordPress knows what URLs should produce a 404 (it is WordPress that triggers the 404). `.htaccess` is processed long before WordPress gets to handle the request. You need to do this in WordPress/PHP, not `.htaccess`.